# Filter stage gets lost in RDD lineage re-execution

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question about RDD and the lineage graph. Let me illustrate with an example:
I have a data file that looks like this:

```
ID; parent; level; type;content; Budget;
999999 ;;a;Total;total; 313344394;
01 ;;a;Part 1;Chancellery of the President of the Republic of Poland; 171524;
02 ;;a;Part 2;Chancellery of the Sejm; 430780;
03 ;;a;Part 3;OFFICE OF THE SENATE; 176212;
04 ;;a;Part 4;SUPREME COURT; 88161;
```

Note that for the last budget field, there is a leading space.
So I read in the data, create an RDD consisting of selected columns:

```
scala>  val baseRDD=sc.textFile(dataFile)
baseRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[103] at textFile at <console>:29

scala> val budgetRDD=baseRDD.map(_.split(";")).map(x => (x(0),x(4), x(5))) 
budgetRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[101] at map at <console>:31
```

Now, I filter out the header row and obtain the last column as an int:

```
scala> val headerRow=budgetRDD.first
headerRow: (String, String, String) = (ID,content,Budget)

scala> val idBudgetRDD = budgetRDD.filter(_!=headerRow).map{case(id,name,money) => 
(id,money.toInt)}

idBudgetRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[105] at map at <console>:46

scala> idBudgetRDD.toDebugString
res143: String = 
(2) MapPartitionsRDD[105] at map at <console>:46 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[104] at filter at <console>:46 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[101] at map at <console>:31 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[100] at map at <console>:31 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[99] at textFile at <console>:29 []
|  /home/user/poland_budget_2011_small.txt HadoopRDD[98] at textFile at <console>:29 []
```

So the lineage graph above clearly has the filter step.
Now I take a peek at my data and get an error:

```
scala> idBudgetRDD.take(2)
16/02/12 03:43:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 146.0 (TID 179)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 313344394"
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

This is understandable because of the leading space in the Budget column.
So instead of using trim, I edited and removed the leading space in the data file:

```
ID; parent; level; type;content;Budget;
999999 ;;a;Total;total;313344394;
01 ;;a;Part 1;Chancellery of the President of the Republic of Poland;171524;
02 ;;a;Part 2;Chancellery of the Sejm;430780;
03 ;;a;Part 3;OFFICE OF THE SENATE;176212;
04 ;;a;Part 4;SUPREME COURT;88161;
```

Having made this change, and with the lineage graph above, my expectation would be that re-running the `take` action would re-execute the lineage graph and produce the desired result. But this wasn't the case, instead I get another error, indicating that the filter step to exclude the header row was not applied:

```
scala> idBudgetRDD.take(2)
16/02/12 03:47:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 147.0 (TID 180)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Budget"
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Can someone explain what is happening ? My thought was that due to lazy evaluation and lineage, fixing the data file and re-executing `take` would cause the lineage graph to be re-run in its entirety.

Comment: What does your `headerRow` variable contains?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line and I added it above: `val headerRow=budgetRDD.first`

Comment: And did you updated this variale before doing again the `take`?

Comment: Aah, now  I get it. The headerRow variable needed to have been updated since it was materialized. Error on my part, thanks. I suppose that if I replaced the variable in the filter step with something like
 `val dataRows=budgetRDD.filter(_!=budgetRDD.first)` that might work.

Comment: I tried using the filter above and got the following error:
`16/02/12 05:14:47 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 149.0 (TID 182, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the filter I was using above was fixed, hence after I modified the file it was no longer applicable. I was able to solve this problem by specifying a filter which was dependent on matching the ID string as follows:

```
val idBudgetRDD = budgetRDD.filter(! _.0.startsWith("ID;")).map{case(id,name,money) => (id, money.toInt)}
```

This always matches the header row and re-running take produces the right result.